# What does "life gets done" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From a Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308882) (emphasis mine):

> How did people calculate sine and cosine or logarithms or even multiply big numbers before there were calculators? They used books with tables inside, along with the training to use those tables properly. Or they used slide rules.
>
> **Life gets done**. The tools change. But life still gets done.

What does "life gets done" mean? Is it a phrase? I know "to get something done" means to do something, but "life gets done" makes no sense for me, and googling it does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a standard phrase, but the natural reading in that context is that the job (of calculating) is performed regardless of the tools employed.

Comment: How "life" is related?

Comment: @enkryptor There's a related phrase [*life goes on*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/life-goes-on), but it's not directly applicable here. "Life" is used in the sense of "all the things you do in life". I'd read it as a [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) for the part of life that calls for making the various calculations referred to in the quote.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it means despite what the situation is or what the problems and hurdles are, life keeps going. It doesn't stop for anything or anyone.